# Redux Thunk Async React Component Did mount

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAccountData();
}
render() {
    const { accounts  } = this.props.accountData;
    policyDetailsInfo =  accounts[0].policy_summary;
    accountDetails = accounts[0];
    return (
      <div>
        <Account
          accountDetails={accountDetails}
          policyDetails={policyDetailsInfo}
        />
      </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  accountData: state.accountData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchAccountData
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AccountHome);
```

1. Here into the componentDidMount the fetchAccountData method is the
   async call.
2. Here I want when the fetchAccountData response get
   after that only control go into the render method. Here it will so
   many times go into the render method till the async call method gets
   response.
3. Due to this control go into the child component and that component did
   not get the property which probably will fill after the response
   from the async call.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you properly configured the reducer, whenever the async call response arrives, the `render()` method `AccountHome` component will be triggered (as there is a change in a `accountData`, state which the `AccountHome` is registered to)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  accountData: state.accountData
})
```

You have many ways to write a logic to handle the accountData, but for simplicity and focusing in the code you paste, update the `render()` method and make it aware about the `accountData prop`:

```
render() {
  const accounts = this.props.accountData;
  if(!accounts || !accounts.length ) {
    // set a simple loading solution
    // avoid errors using empty accounts
    return (
      <div>
        Loading content...
      </div>
    }
  }

  // here accounts has data inside
  const policyDetailsInfo =  accounts[0].policy_summary;
  const accountDetails = accounts[0];

  return (
    <div>
      <Account
        accountDetails={accountDetails}
        policyDetails={policyDetailsInfo}
      />
    </div>
  }
}
```